# WSL PATH contains windows directories, How to (elegantly) fix it to exclude only certain ones?

Tags: linux, windows, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been tinkering with WSL2 and found out that when trying to use some software, such as `gcloud`  I bump into an annoying inconvenience.

```sh
$ gcloud
/mnt/c/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: 113: exec: python: not found
```

This happens because the `PATH` variable in WSL is set by default to include some windows directories. If we examine it, we can find `/mnt/c/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud` amongst the set directories:

```sh
$ echo $PATH | grep /mnt/c/google-cloud-sdk/bin/
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Azure/CLI2/wbin:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/Users/iyid/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/iyid/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/snap/bin
```

I can understand why there are some windows directories such as `/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin`, or `/mnt/c/Users/iyid/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin` because I use them, but when `gcloud` is unusable "out-of-the-box", why include it?

So an ugly fix is to just export a new `PATH` variable that excludes the `gcloud` directory, and add this to `.bashrc` within the user & root home directories. Note that when replacing the path variable, I need to manually set double-quotes `"` around directories with spaces in it, such as `"/mnt/c/Users/iyid/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"`, which makes the fix even uglier. What If I install some other software and need to include its binaries in the `PATH` variable? Should I just pile-up path update instructions in my `.bashrc`? What If I want to use `zsh` later-on, and I have to switch all the instructions to `.zshrc`? etc... All of these questions make this solution purely a "workaround" that involves a lot of maintenance overhead.

Is there a more elegant way to fix this issue?

Comment: Actually, replacing the PATH variable once seems to work perfectly because it modifies windows' environment variables for the user, but the system variables stay the same. So I only need to change it once, not put it in the `.bashrc`, this way, I can get `gcloud` in both environments : WSL & Windows